# PV=constant and V/T=constant then why PT is not constant?

Tags: gas-laws

We know that ***P<sub>1</sub>V<sub>1</sub>=P<sub>2</sub>V<sub>2</sub>*** by ***Boyle's Law***. Let's say this equation (i).

And we know that ***V<sub>1</sub>/T<sub>1</sub>=V<sub>2</sub>/T<sub>2</sub>*** by ***Charle's Law***. Let this equation be (ii).

Dividing (i)/(ii), we get ***P<sub>1</sub>T<sub>1</sub>=P<sub>2</sub>T<sub>2</sub>***...

But it's completely wrong as ***Gay-Lussac's Law*** says
***P<sub>1</sub>/T<sub>1</sub>=P<sub>2</sub>/T<sub>2</sub>***

So where am I wrong ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boyle's law is valid when temperature is constant. Charles law is valid when pressure is constant. If you are using both laws to deduce an equation in P and T, you have to assume that both pressure and temperature are constant. If you assume that, both Gay-Lussac's Law and the equation $P_1T_1=P_2T_2$ hold good.

Comment: But if P and T are constant, no change can happen, as the number of moles has not changed.